# How read a file inside a subfolder of webroot in CakePHP?

Tags: xml, cakephp, directory

I need read a XML inside my app/webroot/xml folder, what variables should I use for this?

Thanks,
Celso

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Webroot can be accessed from the root of the app. As long as the location exists in webroot, you will not get an error. So to access anything in webroot, you simply reference: /
So if you want to access a file in webroot/xml, you can access it from:

```
http://yourdomain/xml/
```

If you are accessing from within the cake code (not via the web), you should use:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(WWW_ROOT . DS . 'myDoc.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
WEBROOT_DIR . DS . "xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are calling the xml doc from views->layouts->default.ctp then

```
<?php $xml = simplexml_load_file("xml/myDoc.xml"); ?>
```

Should work just fine.